# Oracle sql to_char date conversion produces invalid output

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

We're using Oracle 11g here with some pretty vanilla SQL. Due to some new client requirements we need to output submission dates and times with milliseconds to 3 decimal places. Since they also want legacy data also to have the same output I've came up with the following:

```
SELECT
NVL( CD.RECEIPT_DATE_TS, CAST(CD.RECEIPT_DATE AS TIMESTAMP) ) as receipt_ts,
TO_CHAR(NVL( CD.RECEIPT_DATE_TS, CAST(CD.RECEIPT_DATE AS TIMESTAMP) ) , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MM:SSxFF3' ) as RECEIPT_TS_conv,
etc.
```

However the output shows the following:

```
receipt_ts_no_convert          receipt_ts_conv
4/16/2018 5:08:10.657463 PM    2018-04-16 17:04:10.657
4/16/2018 12:00:00.000000 AM   2018-04-16 00:04:00.000
4/13/2018 7:48:41.105792 PM    2018-04-13 19:04:41.105
```

As you can see on those entries with a time like 4/16/2018 12:00:00.000000 AM appears to add the month number to the minutes, as in 2018-04-16 00:04:00.000.

Ideally the output for that entry should look be 2018-04-16 00:00:00.000.

I'm not sure of what's going on, and am not sure how to correct this. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be most appreciated.

Many thanks.

larry

Comment: Just FYI it might be better to use `COALESCE()` than `NVL()` - the former is ANSI SQL compliant

Comment: Thanks @DavidFaber I'll check that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your date format, you are using `MM` for both month and minute.  `MM` is month.  Use `MI` for minutes.

Comment: @LarryC.Lyons - many experts have made that mistake at one point or another; it is quite common. Don't worry about it, just remember it the next time it happens to you!

Comment: @mathguy what me worry? (sorry couldn't resist).